# Hibernate envers not working with mssql

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate-envers

I am facing a problem and I can't find a solution for it. I am using Hibernate envers to audit a table (I am using MS SQL as a database).

I get an error when I try to update the table:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '-'. "

Any help ?
Thank you

Comment: We need to see at least the query.

Comment: There is no query I'm using spring data

Comment: If there's no query, how can there be incorrect syntax?

Comment: Please enable debug logging by either enabling `org.hibernate.show_sql=true` in your configuration or set `org.hibernate.SQL` logging level to `TRACE`.  Please, also post the audited entities and your update operation code snippet.

Comment: it's already set to true :jpa:
                                             show_sql: true  
And I just added @Audited into my entity

Comment: Voted to close this question. There is not enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: @HoneyBadger have you ever worked with hibernate envers with mssql ?

Comment: You need to at least show how you're you're interacting with spring-data in order for us to give you some assistance.  There is simply too many possibilities of how a `SQLServerException` can be thrown and the message `Incorrect syntax near '-'` doesn't provide any helpful context to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused because the sql server being generated contains the square braces around the table name.

i.e. [YOUR_TABLE]

When envers is engaged, it attempts to put auditing output into the table [YOUR_TABLE]_AUD, hence the error message indicating a syntax error near the _ character (following the right square brace).